# Set text color in a JTextField without graying out the text

Tags: java, swing, fonts, colors, jtextfield

I am creating a text field that is unable to be modified by the user of my program. When I set the text field so that it cant be modified, the text in the field is grayed out making it difficult to read.

Is there a way to not gray out the text? I have tried using `setForeground` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I thank you can change the disabled text foreground color via the UIManager

Comment: you can set background color of text field

Comment: What is and how would I access the UIManager? I am using JGrasp if that helps.

Comment: `What is and how would I access the UIManager?` - See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). In this case you can't use the UIManager, but its still nice to know that it exists.

Comment: Why cant I use the UIManager in this case? I went to the link you posted but I dont see why I cant use it in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try setDisabledTextColor?

Comment: +1, The API is always the best place to look (I also looked at the UIManager Defaults first).

Answer (score 0):

use `JLabel` instade of `JTextField` , `JLabel` has the same `JTextField` Functions and cannot  be Modified by User Also the background will be normal not gray